# Should there be (alternate) countries tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Example question: [Getting rid of democracy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/72586/getting-rid-of-democracy)

OP in this question specifically asks about how to get United Kingdom out of current democracy. When reading this question, I got thought: **Having country specific tag would make that question more clear** in my opinion.

And it is not only this question. Some [near-future](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-future) questions ask about USA, United Kingdom and sometimes other countries.

I am not suggesting tags for all countries, but I think that having tags for at least USA and UK could help to add more clarity to questions being asked

### Cons

Only argument against I can imagine is, that such tags could be misleading and have users believe we talk real issues here. However, that could be fixed by clear tag wiki description

What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags are not for clarifications. Their main purpose is categorization and search.

To see if tag makes sense, ask yourself few questions:

1. Can you  imagine someone being expert in such tag?
2. Can  you imagine someone searching for questions with such tag?
3. Or ignoring them  on purpose?

In  my opinion, answers are:

1. Not  really, because fictional analogs of any given country may vary wildly
2. Maybe?
3. No, I can't.

And because of that, my answer is firm **no**.

On  the   other hand, maybe tag country-specific would make sense? But that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

We have tag for [japan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japan). We also have [united-states](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states). I don't think you need "alt-Japan" also. If you wish to introduce a new tag for specific nations, I think that's appropriate as it helps with indexing.